# Is the infinite $\sum_n \frac{1}{2^{a_n}}$ always exist for any increasing natural number sequence $a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The motivation is that, assuming the $\sum_n b_n$ exists, then, selecting a subset of $b_n$, the infinite sum still intuitively exists.

Let $a_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive nature number.

$a_{n+1}>a_n$

Does the following sum always exist and computable?

$$S_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{a_n}}$$

Intuitively the answer is yes because there is an upper-bound. But I don't know how to rigorously prove it.

Comment: Hint:  compare to the geometric series $\sum \frac 1{2^n}$

Comment: Do you mean that $a_n$ are natural numbers for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Where did this question come from? What have you tried? This question doesn't meet the MSE Guidelines. -1

Comment: @bb_823 Yes all $a_n$ are natural numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "positive nature number" you mean natural numbers. Since this sequence is monotonically increasing, that means $n\le a_n,\forall n\in \mathbb{n}$. From there we can see $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{a_n}}\le\frac{1}{2^n}$, which implies $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{a_n}}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$. Since we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$ is [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) that [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) we can also say that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{a_n}}$ converges.

Comment: I think you are right. But how to go from $S_n\leq \sum_n\frac{1}{2^n}<1$ to $S_n$ converges?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ is equal to 1 not less than 1. We know $0\le S_n\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^n}}.$ Meaning $S_n$ is between $0$ and $1$, so obviously it converges.

Comment: @High GPA - The partial sums $S_n$ are monotonically increasing and bounded above by $1.$

Comment: @bb_823 I don't think "between 0 and 1" is enough. For example, check $0.6-0.5+0.5-0.5+0.5-...$. This series is between 0 and 1 and it does not converge

Comment: @HighGPA you’d be right that was a wrong statement by me, but look at the first statement in my comment and look at [comparison test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcII/seriescomptest.aspx). As you see we can’t say $\sum 0.5\le \sum\frac{1}{2^n}$, because it is incorrect for all $n>1$. Also check the comment by Chris Leary.